# MySQL - Counting results for different criteria in case of multiple rows output

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, counting

I have to get results based on 4 different criteria for an XLS export.

**Here is the create table code :**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `relation_tc_agri` (
  `tc_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `agri_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `state` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `send_email` smallint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  KEY `tc_id` (`tc_id`),
  KEY `agri_id` (`agri_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

**And some examples (slightly modified for the sake of presentation) :**

```
+-----------+-------------+-------+------------+
| tc_id     | agri_id     | state | send_email |
+-----------+-------------+-------+------------+
| 045bd915c | 2a6ad61aa   | 0     | 1          |
| f50d6b1eb | 413bc4026   | 1     | 1          |
| f50d6b1eb | 1475f4ba4   | 1     | 1          |
| f50d6b1eb | 1475f4ba4   | 2     | 1          |
| gd865be6e | 1475f4ba4   | 2     | 1          |
| d0dbfa93d | 90b3fefcf   | 3     | 0          |
+-----------+-------------+-------+------------+
```

I have four different state (0, 1, 2 and 3) and have to count how many results there is for each one, for each tc_id.

**Expected output :**

```
+-----------+------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| tc_id     | total rows | rows with state 1| rows with state2| rows with state3|
+-----------+------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 045bd915c | 1          | 0                | 0               | 0               |
| f50d6b1eb | 3          | 2                | 1               | 0               |
| gd865be6e | 1          | 0                | 1               | 0               |
| d0dbfa93d | 1          | 0                | 0               | 1               |
+-----------+------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Counting the total number of rows (state 0, 1, 2 and 3) for each tc_id is no problem using :

```
COUNT(*) AS "total rows"
```

But when it comes to counting rows with state 1 or 2 or 3, I'm stuck with errors. I tried several JOIN and even subqueries (which is bad and slow), IN to get rid of the "Subquery return more than 1 result" message and so on.

It would be greatly appreciated to have someone putting me on the right path ;)

Thanks a lot in advance !

Cheers.

Em.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation.  In MySQL this looks like:

```
select tc_id, count(*) as totalrows,
       sum(state = 1) as state_1,
       sum(state = 2) as state_2,
       sum(state = 3) as state_3
from relation_tc_agri
group by tc_id;
```

MySQL treats boolean values as numbers, with true being `1` and false being `0`.  Just taking the sum counts the number of times the value is true.

Comment: Nice trick. I always solved these problems in this way:
SUM(IF(state = 1, 1, 0)) as state_1
but from now i will always use your suggestion

Comment: Great Gordon ! I tried many different approaches but did not think about that. It works perfectly, thanks for the fast and efficient answer ;)